# Show all library functions in autocomplete with Cider

Tags: auto-complete-mode, clojure, cider

When I have imported the `reagent.core` library as `reagent` and I type `(reagent/` I want to see all possible functions from that library I can use, preferably with documentation. Unfortunately I get only suggestions of text I already typed in that file:

[image: not enough suggestions]

I want to see something similar as this, only then for reagent.

[image]

I am using `ac-cider` and `auto-complete` packages with the following settings:

```
;; Auto-completion
(require 'ac-cider)    
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook 'ac-flyspell-workaround)
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook 'ac-cider-setup)
(add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook 'ac-cider-setup)

(require 'auto-complete)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'cider-mode)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'cider-repl-mode)

(defun set-auto-complete-as-completion-at-point-function ()
  (setq completion-at-point-functions '(auto-complete)))
(add-hook 'auto-complete-mode-hook 'set-auto-complete-as-completion-at-point-function)
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook 'set-auto-complete-as-completion-at-point-function)

(defun clojure-auto-complete-hook ()
  (auto-complete-mode 1))

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'clojure-auto-complete-hook)
```

How can I see all possible functions to use from an external library when I type the imported name?

Comment: I've created a cross post to this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859711/code-completion-for-external-libraries-for-spacemacs. I have switched to Spacemacs, but there I have the same problem as in an Emacs version where I setup everything manually.